# Grouping table data into columns rather then rows

Tags: css, html, semantics

Most of the time it makes sense to organize table data in rows. However right now I'm dealing with a table that compares data across several columns. Each column is a product, so I'd like to keep all product data grouped together.

```
<tr> 
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Price</td>
  <td>Weight</td>
  <td>Height</td>
  <td>Compatibility</td>
  <td>Designer</td>
  <td>Manufacturer</td>
  <td>Age Requirement</td>
</tr>
```

Using the TR tag that row will run horizontally, is there a way to make it run vertically?

Update:
I would like the table to display like regular html in this example:

```
<tr>  
  <td>Name</td> 
  <td>Name2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Price</td> 
  <td>Price2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Weight</td> 
  <td>Weight2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Height</td> 
  <td>Height2</td> 
</tr>
```

However I would like to be able to code it by related content:

```
<tr>  
  <td>Name</td> 
  <td>Price</td> 
  <td>Weight</td> 
  <td>Height</td> 
</tr>  

<tr>  
  <td>Name</td> 
  <td>Price</td> 
  <td>Weight</td> 
  <td>Height</td> 
</tr>
```

In other words, I want the table row tag (tr) to act like a column.

Comment: Long time ago, but have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr>  
  <td>Name</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Price</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Weight</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Height</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Compatibility</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Designer</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Manufacturer</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Age Requirement</td> 
</tr>
```

If you want another product beside it, you would do:

```
<tr>  
  <td>Name</td> 
  <td>Name2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Price</td> 
  <td>Price2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Weight</td> 
  <td>Weight2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Height</td> 
  <td>Height2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Compatibility</td> 
  <td>Compatibility2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Designer</td> 
  <td>Designer2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Manufacturer</td> 
  <td>Manufacturer2</td> 
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>Age Requirement</td> 
  <td>Age Requirement2</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: The issue with that is when there are 4 columns. It's still grouping by row.

Comment: I've thought about just using multiple tables, but that won't work because if a comparison row item is multiple lines and its counterparts are single line we'll run into alignment issues unless we force each cell height.

Comment: I'm not following, can you provide sample output?

Comment: When you say "grouping" do you mean you want the HTML for a product to be together? If so, not sure why that matters...

Comment: Yes. I'd like all the data to be together. 

I'm going to be placing ajax calls to update columns, it'll would be really nice have all the data in one place.

This is a case of #lazyweb

Comment: In this case I would return `JSON` data rather than `HTML`, and then it is easy client-side to update the rows accordingly.

Comment: but then I have to map all the objects... *grumble*  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This solution may not work on older browsers, but something along the lines of this approach generally works for me:

```
<style>
  .col {
    display: table-cell;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="col">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col">Column 3</div>
</body>
```